# Laravel - Model validation with non database fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I would like to perform my validation in my models. This way, I can have multiple controllers trigger the same validation yet keeping my code very DRY. This works, however I run into an issue when I have a field that I do NOT want stored to the database (ie: password_confirmation).

My code is here: 
http://laravel.io/bin/xVEd

On line 132, I have:

```
$validation = Validator::make($this->getAttributes(), static::$rules);
```

I defined the property of password_confirmation in the user model so as to tell eloquent that it is not a DB attribute. Now I just need a way to send it to this validator in the base model that does NOT prevent me from using this base model as a parent to models that do not have this issue.

Possibly also, another root cause of this might be the fact that i have the setAttribute message for password creating a hash. As such the two will never match.

Comment: Overwrite `getAttributes`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the issue is the Hash. Not the get Attributes.

Comment: The issue is the hash, I have the exact same issue. Did you find any solution on this?